# How to load HTML String into Web Kit View?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I get this response from the API

I pasted it on the link below.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gvkM_ajvmtpqRRbUXdcZxgTK0O-DmkWPlLkIs5CtwN4/edit?usp=sharing

It's an HTML String with Javascript.

I would like to load it using `WebKitView`.

But simply calling `webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)` does not work.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223699/load-local-html-javascript-with-wkwebview-ios

Comment: Can you test the script locally? Because its not working on my macbook browser either.

Comment: It's a different case, they are loading an HTML file locally. I get mine from an API Response

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
htmlString = htmlString.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).joined()
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```