# Local HTML5 game does not load in UIWebKit

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I'm trying load local html5 game in UIWebKit, but it stop loading on 85%. The game successfully load in Safari and works.

This is my MainViewController:

[image: Controller]

Here is you can see failure loading of html5 game on simulator (on device same result):

[image: simulator]

Safari:

[image: Safari]

May be someone knows what I'm doing wrong? I thought that in my UIWebKit disabled Javascript, but it always enable by default.

P.S.
Link to the game: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zStW12yg_EFC5ks8EZE7kvKgrwi9sdTi

Comment: So, I understood that loading page is static and percents is always 85% (just a picture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223699/load-local-html-javascript-with-wkwebview-ios).

In order to play JavaScript in local, you must run a local webserver with GCDWebServer.

Comment: Could you share result or code example how do you finally made it works using GCDWebServer with your case and game, please?